# How to get live data from Alpha Vantage?

Tags: alpha-vantage

I have tried using the following to get live stock information but it is pulling information from the previous day.

```
import pandas as pd
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries

def AlphaVantage(symbol):
     ts = TimeSeries(key="mykey")
     data, _ = ts.get_quote_endpoint(symbol)
     print(data)

AlphaVantage('MSFT')
```

I have also tried using the follow pieces of code I found on the pandas data reader site:

```
import os

from datetime import datetime

import pandas_datareader.data as web

web.get_quote_av(["AAPL", "TSLA"])
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
keyerror: 'stock quotes'
```

Is it not possible to get live data? 
Does anyone have advice on how I can achieve this?

Comment: When are you running the code? If the market is closed, you'll be getting the data from the previous close. Could you attach timestamps with timezones?

Answer (score 0):

I am also having this problem! Seems to be new though?

NYSE is live right now however running (with API key):

```
data, meta_data = ts.get_intraday(symbol='AAPL', outputsize='full', interval='1min')
```

gives data starting from previous day at close:

```
                        open     high       low     close     volume
date   


2020-05-21 16:00:00  317.090  317.530  316.5800  316.9600   836354.0
2020-05-21 15:55:00  317.790  318.000  317.0100  317.0662   355895.0
2020-05-21 15:50:00  318.104  318.104  317.4800  317.7600   240174.0
2020-05-21 15:45:00  318.010  318.330  317.6819  318.1002   242233.0
2020-05-21 15:40:00  317.610  318.150  317.3000  318.0350   229214.0
...                      ...      ...       ...       ...        ...
2020-05-04 09:55:00  287.880  289.290  287.7300  288.8400   794257.0
2020-05-04 09:50:00  286.945  287.870  286.6850  287.8300   592501.0
2020-05-04 09:45:00  287.660  287.870  286.3172  286.9600   727985.0
2020-05-04 09:40:00  288.410  288.600  287.4800  287.7399   669845.0
2020-05-04 09:35:00  289.170  289.580  287.4300  288.3400  1835406.0

[1092 rows x 5 columns]
```

Seems to be that some tickers work but others don't! Equities mostly work though. Very odd.